# why my code is not work on block body drupal

Tags: forms, blocks

```
function confirm_form($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $c_user=user_load_by_mail($user->mail);
  $query = db_select('import_contact');
  $query->fields('import_contact', array('name', 'email', 'company', 'operator_insert', 'status', 'matches'))
    ->condition('email', $c_user->mail,'=')
    ->condition('status', 'pending', '=');

  $bolean = $query->execute();
  $data = $bolean->fetchAssoc();
  $check = $bolean->rowCount();

  if(!$check = 0) { 
    $data = $bolean->fetchAssoc();
    $nama = $data['name'];
    $company = $data['company'];
  }

  echo "you have been invited by " . $company ".to join.";

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;    
}
```

Comment: please explain what your trying to do, in your question

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Dumping a wedge of code into a question and asking us to guess what you're trying to do, guess what's wrong, and provide you with a fix is bad form - we don't allow it here. We'd love to help with your problem, but to do that we'll need to know what your problem actually is. Please add as much detail as necessary to explain the problem domain, what you expect to happen, what actually happens, and what (if any) error messages you receive. Please see [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The most evident errors are:

- [confirm_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/confirm_form/7) is a Drupal function; you cannot define a function with that name.
- There isn't any reason to use `user_load_by_mail($user->mail)` when you need only `$user->mail`, and you can use `$user->mail` directly, which is what your code is already doing.
- `!$check = 0` is assigning `0` to `$check` and then checking `$check` is not zero. What you want is `!check`.
- A form builder should never use `echo`. `echo "you have been invited by " . $company ".to join.";` contains an error, as you moved the concatenation operator inside the string to the right, and PHP is complaining about that.